# Folder with special characters py2exe

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, py2exe

In my code, I call a file that is located in a folder called "Física" (please note that the "i" is acute).

I don't have any problem running this in my IDE (Spyder), but after I turn my program into an executable with py2exe I get an error:

```
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed'"
```

The problem is because of these special characters. How can I solve this problem?

I tried to do the following

```
path = unicode(path).encode('utf-8')
```

to treat the path with utf-8 encoding. But if I do this my path will be:

`F\xc3\xadsica` instead of `Física`

Comment: How are you setting `path`? That function (whatever it is) needs to return unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong:

I wanted to read a file from that path, and then write a file to the same path. I was encoding the path in utf-8 when saving it in a variable. However, I was not using the decode when using that variable to write in the path.

I need to use ´encode('utf-8')´ when saving the path to a variable and then use ´decode('utf-8')´ when setting the destination path. Thank you so much and sorry for the poor explanation